# HTTP ERROR 500 - after all configurations as said by creator

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter project (opensourcepos). I have done all configurations as said but there's an error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpdWX.png)
Please help me out...

I have tried to change the .htaccess file many times but in vain...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the actual error is not being displayed so you can't properly diagnostic it.

Depending on the CI settings and version (please specify) it hides the error and only shows a standard server 500.

Details:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html